# What is the mean of the four numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given four numbers, with the property that how ever you choose three of them, they always have the arithmetic mean of $2016.$ What is the mean of all four numbers?

---

Let the four numbers be $a,b,c,d$ and $a,b,c$ be the three numbers whose mean is $2016.$ We have that

$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}=2016\Leftrightarrow a+b+c=6048.$$

So, $$\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}=\frac{6048+d}{4}=?$$

Now what?

Comment: Consider adding together the arithmetic means of each of the possible subsets of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ consisting of three elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For the mean of three to stay the same when you switch one out for another, the one you switch out and the one that comes in must have the same value.

Comment: Ahh, I misenterpreted the question. I thought that out of the three, the mean of them is 2016 no matter in what order you chose to add them. So this means that all the numbers has to be the same? $\frac{a+a+a}{3}=2016$ and $\frac{a+a+a+a}{4}=2016$ which implies that $a=2016$?

Comment: @Parseval: That's how I understood the question.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Add the four averages. What do you get (both in letters and in value)?

Alternatively, subtract one of the averages from another, what do you get?

Comment: There is only one average here, that is given, 2016. The other average is to be found.

Comment: No, there are four averages. The average of $a,b,c$, the average of $a,b,d$, the average of $a,c,d$ and the average of $b,c,d$.

Comment: You\re right, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

If the mean of any 3 of these numbers is always 2016, you can for example write, simply by changing one number:

$$\frac{a+b+c}{3} = \frac{a+b+d}{3} = 2016$$

What property tying the 4 numbers can you find from there ?

Comment: From that equation, it follows that $c=d.$

Comment: .. which in turn (if one writes more equations like this) means that $a=b=c=d.$

Comment: And there you have it, you solved your problem.